# Centering a span horizontally after centering it vertically

Tags: html, css

After going through the long process of learning how to vertically centre a span in a div, at the end, my text content is no longer centered horizontally despite having set text-align: center. Also, very strangely to note, the horizontal centering DOES WORK only when the text within the span wraps to a second line.

```
enter code here

<div class="tier_blurb dh"> 
   <div class="blurb_title">
      <span>Assign ownership</span>
   </div>Engage your team to align business process responsibilities to their respective owners while performing initial cost benefits analysis on the business opportunities available</div>
</div>

.blurb_title {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 43px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.blurb_title span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: A few pointers: You have an extra closing `</div>` which should be removed. I wouldn't use `display: table-cell;` to center the `span` - this is why it is not centered as the `div` is shrinking to fit the text not the width of the container. What result are you after exactly? It's possible this could be tackled from a different angle.

Comment: Please, fix your code, you forget a `<div>` before 'Engage your...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `width` attribute for `.blurb_title` because any table cell without specified width will get width of its content.

```css
.blurb_title {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 43px;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier_blurb dh"> 
   <div class="blurb_title">
      <span>Assign ownership</span>
   </div>Engage your team to align business process responsibilities to their respective owners while performing initial cost benefits analysis on the business opportunities available</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flex-box:

```
.blurb_title {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that center aligning does not work if width property is not specified or set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Follow the references [CSS Flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Centering Things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

You can also use CSS Flex-box (My Recommendation)

`display: flex; 
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center;`

```css
.blurb_title {
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier_blurb dh">
  <div class="blurb_title">
    <span>Assign ownership</span>
  </div>
  Engage your team to align business process responsibilities to their respective owners while performing initial cost benefits analysis on the business opportunities available
</div>
```